# Magento how to call Parent's parent function?

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I have overridden the class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid` . This class is extended from `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`. And I want to call the `_prepareCollection()` of `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` function inside my class. How can I do this? I have tried with `parent::_prepareCollection();`. But it loads the immediate parent's method. But I want to call parent's parent class functions. Any suggestions please?

my class is as follows.

```
class Test_ExtendedGrid_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
{
    // some code
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. The following line made the trick.

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is about calling a parent's parent, however the answer doesn't do that I'm afraid.

In Magento (version 2 at the time of writing this), you can use the getParentBlock() function taken from the parent as follows:

```
parent::getParentBlock()->DoSomething();
```

i.e. to call the function in your answer, you would do:

```
parent::getParentBlock()->_prepareCollection();
```

I hope this helps.

H